# Determinant bundle of subvector bundle provides subline bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, projective-space

Let $F,\,F'$ be two locally free sheaves (of rank $n$) over $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ for some field $k$ such that $F'$ is a subsheaf of $F$. Let $E'$ and $E$ denote the corresponding vector bundles.

The determinant bundle $E$ is the line bundle $ \det E$ defined by the gluing data determined by the determinant of the transition matrices of trivializations of $E$.

> Now I wonder if $G,\,G'$ denote the locally free sheaves of rank 1 corresponding to $\det E,\,\det E'$, is $G'$ a subsheaf of $G$?

Another linked question is

> Do we have at least $\deg \det E' \leq \deg \det E$?

---

My original thoughts were considering the invariants of $E,\,E'$ regarding their unique decomposition into a direct sum of line bundles
$$E = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^1}}(d_i),\quad
E' = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^1}}(d_i'). $$
I think, in general, we do not have a relation such $d_i' \leq d_i$ but I assume we have at least $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i' \leq \sum_{i=1}^n d_i$.
But the latter two are nothing else than the degrees of $\det E'$ and $\det E$.

I would appreciate any kind of help, references etc. Thank you very much!

Comment: Determinants of locally free sheaves are obtained by taking maximal exterior powers. Then, you will easily get $\det F'=G'\subset G=\det F$ and this easily implies $\deg G'\leq \deg G$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f \colon F' \to F$ is an embedding of sheaves of the same rank, then $\det(f) \colon \det(F') \to \det(F)$ is an embedding too.

Comment: Could you please give me a good reference for this?

Comment: Just restrict to the generic point.